# I see nothing but a bunch of letters. I don't know where a word begins and ends. Some people can read within 2 weeks of learning alphabet from scratch

Tags: arabic, quran-recitation, reading-quran

Assalamualaikum. I know the entire Arabic alphabet, the 4 different shapes of letters. I have begun grammar but it is difficult. Remembering dictionary is also difficult. But I have seen many people that within 2 weeks, they begin reading Quran even though they may be zero in grammar and dictionary. I have tried to read quran but I see nothing but a bunch of letters and I don't have the slightest idea where a word begins and where it ends. Also I don't know when two or more words are united. Can you give me a hint how to distinguish those things when I read quran? Please give me some help.

Comment: I sent this question in the past and reply was: Arabic generally has spaces between words, same as English. I don't know where you find this < Arabic generally has spaces between words, same as English.>. If you open the quran, all the letters are one after the other and you cannot tell which letter is part of what word unless you know the Arabic words by heart. Not only that but there are many words that unite to form compounds of two or three words. Not only that but I have seen words that looked as if they were an entire sentence.

Comment: Perhaps you should try some of the many online courses on reading the Quran.

Answer (score 1):

I completely understand what you are going through as I and all the other people who read the Qur'an have gone through.

I have a couple of suggestions for you.

1. Go to Quran.com and there you will find each aya (Sentence) separated and if you hover over on the aya individual words would highlight and clicking on them would let you listen to each one. That way you can slowly understand how the words are put together.
2. Get a Quran English Translation book and look for one that separates every single word. This is how I taught my little brother since those Quran books are much easier to read for those new to the Quran.

By listening you can atart seeing the rules yourself.